How to make compiler use copy instead of move
I am using msvc compiler with C++ 23
I have a situation like this (class shouldn't be moveable, only copyable):
#include <cstring>

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() = default;

    //copy
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) { data = other.data; }
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other) { data = other.data; return *this; }

    //cannot allow move for this class
    MyClass(MyClass&& other) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other) = delete;

    int data = 0;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass m = MyClass{}; //tries to use move

    //works
    MyClass newm{};
    m = newm;
}

When I do:
MyClass m = MyClass{}; //tries to use move
It tries to move the newly constructed class. I realize that this is natural since MyClass{} is an r-value.
Is there anything that I can do to the class to make this possible? Make the compiler understand that I want it to use copy since move is deleted, so that MyClass m = MyClass{};  works?
Error message:
error C2280: 'MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
message : see declaration of 'MyClass::MyClass'
message : 'MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &&)': function was explicitly deleted


And if you have an hour, you should watch this presentation: The Nightmare of Initialization in C++. It'll help you clear up a lot of problems before they happen.

Try this: a) write Myclass m, n; m=n; to test move=; and write a function that returns a local variable of type MyClass, to test move ctor.

@TopologicalSort m = n; will invoke the copy assignment operator, for the move assignment operator you would need m = std::move(n); instead. Also, a function that returns a named local variable may not invoke the copy constructor or the move constructor at all, if "(Named) Return Value Optimization" (aka copy elison) is used instead.

Just write MyClass m; or, if you're compulsive, MyClass m{};. There's no reason to make the construction more complicated.

Make that m=n1+n2.


I am using msvc compiler with C++ 23

Are you SURE you are actually compiling with C++23? Modern MSVC supports C++23, but it defaults to C++14.  To actually enable C++23, you need to use the /std flag in your configuration.
In C++17 and later, MyClass m = MyClass{}; is optimized to be identical to MyClass m{}; but that is not the case in earlier versions.
Your code compiles fine in msvc v19 using /std:c++latest.
Online Demo
